# I am not getting any container info from my storage account when using the "get-azstoragecontainer" command powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-storage-account

when try to get the containers list of my storage account I am getting these 2 errors
`Get-AzStorageContainer : Retry failed after 6 tries. Retry settings can be adjusted in ClientOptions.Retry.`

or
`Get-AzStorageContainer : This request is not authorized to perform this operation. RequestId:0000000...`

when searching over the internet I found this [Microsoft's blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1166011/getting-a-403-error-when-connecting-to-a-blob-cont)

it basically says your network configuration on the storage account is not allowing you to retrieve such information.

I have 1 storage account with the same network configuration (t6hat is working fine and that I can get the list of containers using the same command) so I copied/replicated that config on a different storage account (which is having the issues) but did not work.

The config I did on the storage account not giving me the list of containers is :

1. I added a VNET and created a private endpoint and configured the method "Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses" but I am still getting one of those 2 errors

I am guessing is something related to the network config but I don't know what else to check.

this is the config of one of the storage accounts I am able to get the list of containers it is connected to a VNET with a private endpoint created (1st image)
[image: image 1]

the second image is to show the network config of the storage account I am not able to get the list of containers

[image: image 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem indeed was the configuration of the storage account, in my specific case I needed to create a private endpoint and link that private endpoint to a private DNS zone, after that I was able to access

Answer (score 1):

Created storage account and enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses:

[image]

Created private endpoint in storage account within the virtual network:

[image]

when I tried to get the list of containers it is connected to a VNET with a private endpoint and got the same error:

```
Get-AzStorageContainer : This request is not authorized to perform this operation. RequestId:0000000...
```

[image]

To resolve this issue, check the below steps:

Ensure that in firewall settings add the client IP addresses to allow access from the internet or on-premises network. These rules grant access to specific internet-based services and on-premises networks and block general internet traffic and allow your storage account to retrieve the container list:

[image]

- Check any NSGs associated with the subnet that the private endpoint is connected to. NSGs can block traffic to and from the storage account, even if the private endpoint is configured correctly. Make sure that the NSG rules allow traffic to and from the storage account.
- Check you have added RBAC role Storage blob data contributor for your storage account which should provide the necessary permissions to list containers.

Now, after adding client IP make use of below command to get the list of containers:

```c
$resourceGroupName= "RGName"    
$storageAccName="StorageName"    

#Function to get all the containers    
Function GetAllStorageContainer    
{    
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Retrieving storage container.."        
    ## Get the storage account from which container has to be retrieved    
    $storageAcc=Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $storageAccName        
    ## Get the storage account context    
    $ctx=$storageAcc.Context    
    ## List all the containers    
    $containers=Get-AzStorageContainer  -Context $ctx     
    foreach($container in $containers)    
    {    
        write-host -ForegroundColor Yellow $container.Name    
    }    
}     
    
GetAllStorageContainer
```

[image]

Comment: I followed all your steps but still having the same situation, I was told that DNS config was missing but I am not entirely sure about that, will continue doing some testing and once I have the solution will post it here, thanks for your help, though !